# Python Subprocess Module and Awk

Tags: python

I am trying to implement the following code using subprocess module in python.

```
for i in range(9,17):
    process=s.Popen("awk -v var=$(i) '$6==var' 1GT8.pdb", shell=True, stdout=s.PIPE)

    matched=process.communicate()[0].split()
    print matched
```

But `i` that is being matched is a string entity and not the integer value that I want. Please help me out.

Comment: As usual, the code would be much more elegant *and* efficient if you implemented this logic in pure Python.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not expand variables inside strings, so the command will contain `$(i)` as is. You'll have to insert the value explicitly, like this:

```
command = "awk '$6==\"{}\"' 1GT8.pdb".format(i)
```

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes that are around the brackets, I think.